# imagick with remote url

Tags: php, imagick

here imagick works for image which are stored in server.. but i dont know how to work if i replace with remote url in $paths array

```
$background = new Imagick('back.jpg');
    $paths  = array(
        "img/1.jpg",
        "img/2.jpg",
        "img/3.jpg",
        "img/4.jpg",
    );

    $images = new Imagick($paths);
    foreach($images as $image){
      $image->thumbnailImage($width, NULL);
      $background->compositeImage($image, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, $x ,$y );
    }
```

Comment: Get the image with file_get_contents or something similar, create an image resource from what you get and start working. Or you can download the image to a temporary directory, open it from there and work with that image resource.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to temporarily store the image on your local server:

```
<?php
$remote_image = file_get_contents("http://foo.com/remote_image.jpg");
file_put_contents("/tmp/remote_image.jpg", $remote_image);
$image = new Imagick("/tmp/remote_image.jpg");
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's old but for the record, here's a better way to do this without saving to disk:

```
$image_url = 'http://example.com/input.jpg';
$imageBlob = file_get_contents($image_url);
 
$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->readImageBlob($imageBlob); 

header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
echo $imagick->getImageBlob(); //for animated gifs - getImagesBlob()
```