# How do I open a file in pgmagick (Imagemagick python wrapper), from a URL?

Tags: python, image-processing, imagemagick, graphicsmagick, pgmagick

I was wondering how do I open a file using pgmagick (ImageMagick's Python Wrapper), from a URL?

So far I have tried

i) using BytesIO:

```
from pgmagick import Image
from io import BytesIO

filepath = 'http://example.com/a.jpeg'
response = requests.get(filepath)
im = Image(BytesIO(response.content))
```

which produced the error output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    im = magick_image(BytesIO(response.content))
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    Image.__init__(Image, _io.BytesIO)
did not match C++ signature:
    __init__(struct _object * __ptr64, class Magick::Image)
    __init__(class boost::python::api::object, unsigned int, unsigned int, class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >, enum MagickLib::StorageType, class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)
    __init__(struct _object * __ptr64, unsigned int, unsigned int, class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >, enum MagickLib::StorageType, char const * __ptr64)
    __init__(struct _object * __ptr64, class Magick::Blob, class Magick::Geometry, class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)
    __init__(struct _object * __ptr64, class Magick::Blob, class Magick::Geometry, unsigned int, class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)
    __init__(struct _object * __ptr64, class Magick::Blob, class Magick::Geometry, unsigned int)
    __init__(struct _object * __ptr64, class Magick::Blob, class Magick::Geometry)
    __init__(struct _object * __ptr64, class Magick::Blob)
    __init__(struct _object * __ptr64, class Magick::Geometry, class Magick::Color)
    __init__(struct _object * __ptr64, class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)
    __init__(struct _object * __ptr64)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

ii) using BytesIO and Blob:

```
from pgmagick import Image, Blob
from io import BytesIO

filepath = 'http://example.com/a.jpeg'
response = requests.get(filepath)
im = Image(Blob(BytesIO(response.content)))
```

which produced the error output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    im = magick_image(Blob(BytesIO(response.content)))
  File "lib\site-packages\pgmagick\__init__.py", line 16, in __init__
    _pgmagick.Blob.__init__(self, *args)
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    Blob.__init__(Blob, _io.BytesIO)
did not match C++ signature:
    __init__(struct _object * __ptr64, class Magick::Blob)
    __init__(class Magick::Blob {lvalue}, class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)
    __init__(struct _object * __ptr64)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

iii) using StringIO and Blob:

```
from pgmagick import Image, Blob
from io import StringIO

filepath = 'http://example.com/a.jpeg'
response = requests.get(filepath)
img = Image(Blob(StringIO(response.content)))
```

which produced the error output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    img = magick_image(Blob(StringIO(response.content)))
TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes

Process finished with exit code 1
```

iv) using an in-memory file:

```
from pgmagick import Image
from io import BytesIO

filepath = 'http://example.com/a.jpeg'
response = requests.get(filepath)
in_mem_file = io.BytesIO(response.content)
im = Image(in_mem_file)
```

which produced the error output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    im = magick_image(in_mem_file)
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    Image.__init__(Image, _io.BytesIO)
did not match C++ signature:
    __init__(struct _object * __ptr64, class Magick::Image)
    __init__(class boost::python::api::object, unsigned int, unsigned int, class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >, enum MagickLib::StorageType, class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)
    __init__(struct _object * __ptr64, unsigned int, unsigned int, class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >, enum MagickLib::StorageType, char const * __ptr64)
    __init__(struct _object * __ptr64, class Magick::Blob, class Magick::Geometry, class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)
    __init__(struct _object * __ptr64, class Magick::Blob, class Magick::Geometry, unsigned int, class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)
    __init__(struct _object * __ptr64, class Magick::Blob, class Magick::Geometry, unsigned int)
    __init__(struct _object * __ptr64, class Magick::Blob, class Magick::Geometry)
    __init__(struct _object * __ptr64, class Magick::Blob)
    __init__(struct _object * __ptr64, class Magick::Geometry, class Magick::Color)
    __init__(struct _object * __ptr64, class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)
    __init__(struct _object * __ptr64)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

v) using urllib with in memory file:

```
from pgmagick import Image
from io import BytesIO
import urllib.request

filepath = 'http://example.com/a.jpeg'
in_mem_file = io.BytesIO()
urllib.request.urlretrieve(filepath, in_mem_file)
im = Image(in_mem_file)
```

which produced the error output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(filepath, in_mem_file)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 257, in urlretrieve
    tfp = open(filename, 'wb')
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BytesIO

Process finished with exit code 1
```

So none of these methods work.

I have explored several resources online relating to pgmagick and ImageMagick, but the solutions either don't work, like this:

[Opening an Image From a URL with pgmagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22823940/opening-an-image-from-a-url-with-pgmagick)

or they are in another programming language that isn't Python, like these:

[imagick with remote url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518572/imagick-with-remote-url)

[Imagick - Can't read image files from URL.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21330242/imagick-cant-read-image-files-from-url/35243976)

I'm a bit stuck on this so appreciate any help on this please.

Comment: I have never heard of pgmagick as a product from ImageMagick. Are you sure it is not from some other developer. ImageMagick has PythonMagick and there is also Python Wand that uses ImageMagick. But I know of no pgmagick product from ImageMagick.

Comment: In the docs it says it's a python wrapper for GraphicsMagick,
https://pypi.org/project/pgmagick/ .
I just assumed they were same institution.
PythonMagick docs also refers to GraphicsMagick as it's core.
https://pypi.org/project/PythonMagick/ .

Comment: Just checked and apparently GraphicsMagick is a fork of ImageMagick, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraphicsMagick.